# Cambiar formato de input date

Tags: javascript, html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$(".mostrar_fecha").click(function(){
alert($(".fecha_planificacion").val());
});
```

A través de ese `código` obtengo la **fecha** del `input date` pero me la da en el `formato` que pueden ver en la imagen y la deseo en el formato **dia-mes-año** ...¿cómo podría asignarle el formato deseado a ese `input`?

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una solución, hacer el `formateo` manualmente, donde se guarda en la `variable` **formato**, le puedes poner los separadores que gustes slash `/` o guión medio `-`.

Pruébalo.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('#fecha').change(function(){
  
  //se asigna un id al input date y se obtiene el contenido
    var f = $('#fecha').val();
  //Se da el formato de acuerdo a las posiciones
    var formato = f[8]+f[9]+"/"+f[5]+f[6]+"/"+f[0]+f[1]+f[2]+f[3];
  //imprime la variable con la fecha formateada
    alert(formato);
  
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="date" name="nombre" id="fecha" value="2021-03-30"
        placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" value="2020-03-30"
        min="1997-01-01" max="2030-12-31"> 
        
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```